# ReactJs fixed-data-table: data.getObjectAt is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I´m trying to build a JSON configurable data table using the Facebook´s [fixed-data-table](http://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/). I´ve come to my first code as:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import { Table, Column, Cell } from 'fixed-data-table';

const DateCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  <Cell {...props}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col].toLocaleString()}
  </Cell>
);

const LinkCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  <Cell {...props}>
    <a href="#">{data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}</a>
  </Cell>
);

const TextCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  <Cell {...props}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}
  </Cell>
);

const NumericCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  <Cell {...props}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}
  </Cell>
);

const BooleanCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  
  <Cell {...props}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col] ? <Icon name='checkmark' color='green' /> : <Icon name='remove' color='red' />}
  </Cell>
);


class DataTable extends Component {
    state = {
      schema: this.props.schema,
      data: this.props.data,
    }

  getCells = (schema, data) => {

        let columns = [];

        schema.columns.map((column, index) => {

            let cell = (<TextCell></TextCell>);
            let key = column.field + index;

            if (column.type === 'string') {

              cell = (<TextCell 
                          data={this.state.data} 
                          col={column.field}
                        />);
            }

            if (column.type === 'integer') {

              cell = (<NumericCell 
                          data={this.state.data} 
                          col={column.field}
                        />);
            }


            if (column.type === 'boolean') {

              cell = (<BooleanCell 
                          data={this.state.data} 
                          col={column.field}
                        />);
            }


            let col = (<Column 
                          header={column.title}
                          cell={cell}
                          width={100}
                       />);

            columns.push(col);

            return;
          });

      return columns;
    }




  render() {

    let schema = {
      "columns": [
          {
            "title": "Name",
            "field": "name",
            "type": "string",
          },
          {
            "title": "EIN",
            "field": "ein",
            "type": "string",
          },
          {
            "title": "Active",
            "field": "isactive",
            "type": "boolean",
          }
        ],
        "edit": true,
        "delete": true,
        "sort": true
    };

    let data = [
    {
      name: 'Test1',
      ein: '1234',
      isactive: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Test2',
      ein: '123',
      isactive: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Test3',
      ein: '12345',
      isactive: true
    },
    ];

    let columns = this.getCells(schema, data);


    return (
      <Table
        rowHeight={50}
        schemaHeight={50}
        maxHeight={100}
        width={1000}
        height={500}
        rowsCount={data.length}
        {...this.props}>

        {columns}

      </Table>
    );
  }
}

export default DataTable;
```

When running I´m getting the following error:

```
TypeError: data.getObjectAt is not a function
TextCell
D:\\WORKSPACE\test\src\components\shared\DataTable.js:42
  39 | 
  40 | const TextCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  41 |   <Cell {...props}>
**> 42 |     {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}**
  43 |   </Cell>
  44 | );
  45 |
```

I´ve tried different JSON structures with no luck. The data and schema are loaded accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This literally takes some time to wrap ones mind around initially.

I will describe it using references to code in 'fixed-data-table-2'.

The data list when used in the table is wrapped in an object that
consist of the data list and a data list filter array.
Your list data will only show up if you have wrapped it as a
DataListWrapper object along with a filter array where every
entry of the filter array is a boolean specifying if the corresponding
list row will be visible (true) or hidden (false).

See the class BuildObjectDataListStore.
There is a method 'getObjectAt' in there which when called retrieves list row columns based on the input variable name.
For example

```
var {my_id} = list.getObjectAt(44);
```

means that if the list row at index 44 contains a column named 'my_id'
then the value of that column will end up in your my_id variable.
This works only with 'underscore' as delimiter in column names,
so any lists made up of columns such as "my-id" must be converted to
"my_id" before use in '*fixed-data-table*'. There exists a neat conversion table procedure in BuildObjectDataListStore for that.

Here is how you wrap a plain list array 'myList' into an object that
fixed-data-table' can render:

```
this.dataList = new BuildObjectDataListStore(myList);
```

Then this object is wrapped into an object along with a filter array:

```
this.filteredDataList = new DataListWrapper(this.filter, this.dataList);
```

And there you have it; DataListWrapper is a recognized list format that 'fixed-data-table' can render.

Nowadays people use '[fixed-data-table-2](https://github.com/schrodinger/fixed-data-table-2)'
which enjoys continued support by Schrödinger, Inc.
The earlier '[fixed-data-table](https://github.com/facebookarchive/fixed-data-table)' is abandoned as a public component.

Evolving from the foundations of fixed-data-table, the power of fixed-data-table-2 is at least twofold;

- Can cope with thousands of lines of list data without bogging down on
  scrolling and other responsiveness.
- The principle of cell renderers means any row column can be made to render anything
  that HTML5 offers (text, image, video, etc).

So for some applications this list component can be spot on. A drawback can be the initial learning curve of the mentioned wrapping principles and column renderer methods.

Comment: Where is this `BuildObjectDataListStore` coming from? I don't see it anywhere in the `fixed-data-table-2` codebase.

Comment: @Gajus sorry for the confusion. I happened to include one of my own data structures. In my case BuildObjectDataListStore is a renamed fixed-data-table example "FakeObjectDataListStore.js" which they used to load a "fake example demo data". I found I could use it as a basis to load and render my own data. Basically what it does is contain the data you fetch and
become accessed by rendering code. So you define there what parameters you operate on.